# Text in Asterisks in 3rd person singular

Tags: informal-language

> •starts waving my hand faster•

is it idiomatic to use third person singular form when there is first person determiner, my?

I've often seen these constructions in text messages like

> •waves hello•
>
> •gives shy look•

but *starts waving my hand* has first person determiner so I was wondering if it's alright?

Similar question- [When -s is used with third person singular. What's its use in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205547/when-s-is-used-with-third-person-singular-whats-its-use-in-this-context/205652#205652)

Comment: No - it's *not* idiomatic. Note that examples like **waves hello** or **gives shy look** are *reduced* versions of full sentences from which the verb subject has been "deleted". In standard imperatives such as **Come here!** the implied subject is **you**. In your (non-standard, deliberately "quirky") examples the implied subject is **he**. Which is incompatible  with a *first person* possessive determiner. You'd have to say **starts waving his hand faster** - or more naturally, simply discard the awkward determiner: **starts waving hand faster**.

Comment: No. In text messages people often talk in Astericks as if they were scripts. And they deliberately leave out the subject and use third person. For example I sent hi to my friend. He replied, •waves hello• See. He was the one who waved hello not some third person.

Comment: I know the grammar rules which is why I chose the tag informal language

Comment: I know the grammar rules too! The usage you're asking about is deliberately quirky / facetious (imitating stage directions, sports commentary, etc.). To repeat - *syntactically*, the missing but implied subject is always ***he*** - so if you're going to attach a possessive / reflexive element, it has to be compatible: *Rolls on the floor laughing **his** ass off*, for example. This style is often imitated by non-native speakers, so you might occasionally see *Rolls on the floor laughing **my** ass off*, but more often than not that would be from an nns or a "not-very-careful" native speaker.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=asterisk+action&amp=true

Comment: What are you trying to tell me? I'm a competent native speaker telling you what's "natural" for Anglophones. Are you trying to *argue* with me?

Comment: No. I'm just trying to prove my point. The missing subject can't be he. When the person you're talking to is the one who is doing it.   Did you even bother to look at my example?

Comment: You don't really *have* a point! You are simply mistaken!

Comment: how about leaving out the determiner?  then it wouldn't lead to ambiguity.

Comment: *<starts waving hand faster>* - that's what I suggested in my first comment! But idiomatically that doesn't really work with *<laughs ass off>*.

Comment: but why would someone say •laughs his ass off• I'd rather drop the astericks and say •laugh my ass off•  

Comment: Note that this is nothing to do with "ambiguity". It's obvious *who* the unspecified subject is (the speaker / writer). All we're concerned with here is how far you can stretch the rules of standard grammar before they "break" (become *completely* unacceptable, even in informal contexts). Mixing a first person determiner with a syntactically implied third person subject is beyond the pale for the average Anglophone.

Comment: ...also note that it's *not* idiomatic in such contexts to say ***Laugh** my ass off*, whether or not you explicitly precede it by the first person singular pronoun. But you will sometimes encounter the continuous verb form with a deleted subject: ***Laughing** my ass off*, which is perfectly acceptable so far as *basic syntactic agreement* is concerned.

Comment: so even if the speaker uses the 3rd person determiner here . it's clear that it's the speaker doing it not some third person unless he explicitly mentions it.

Comment: @fumblefingers ?

Comment: <Sigh> It's *always* contextually clear that any text presented as per the first word in this comment ***refers to the speaker/writer*** (there is never any ambiguity on that point). We're not talking about making the meaning clear - we're simply talking about how far you can break the basic rules of English in an informal jocular usage like that. And as a rule of thumb, you *can't* break them so far as to create an overt clash between implied subject ***he*** and possessive determiner ***my***.

Comment: yes. even I was dubious about this clash of **he** with **my**. which is why I asked the question. Thank you very much :) and sorry for the argument xD

Comment: You're welcome. I hope things are clearer to you now. SamBC's answer below is perfectly accurate, except that it's more a matter of opinion whether anyone particularly "cares" (or even *notices*) such clashes in informal contexts. Perhaps some people would be more "forgiving, tolerant" than me.

Comment: Yes there are xD.

Answer (score 2):

In these third person actions, however delimited, if one is being consistent one would keep it in the third person.

However, the whole practice of such actions, in asterisks or whatever, is non-standard and very informal, so trying to apply rigorous rules to it is somewhat pointless.

I, personally, would consider your first example wrong. It should be *his (or her) hand*, or just lose the determiner because it's already clipped speech - *starts waving hand*. But in that sort of informal milieu, who cares?

Comment: *<starting to wave hand even faster>* Of course, there are *other* ways of avoiding OP's glaring subject/verb clash!